# LayoutInflate Exception with ViewPager

Tags: android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{urlinq.android.com.edu_chat_lollipop/urlinq.android.com.edu_chat.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

Still getting this message after reinstalling Android Studio. Not sure what exactly is going on here but I got this message after updating the minSDK version.

I have another user who is also using the same files and his application is able to run. This is my fragment that runs the ViewPager. I have a red exclamation mark next to the background on the ViewPager defined in the activity.

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private PagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
private ImageButton signUpBtnToggle;
private ImageButton loginBtnToggle;
private ImageButton loginBtn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
/**
 * Load the login_main.xml layout.
 * In addition, load the ViewPager.
 */
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //initialize viewpager object.
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_main, container, false);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.loginPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new LoginAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));


    final LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable) mViewPager.getBackground();

    background.getDrawable(0).setAlpha(0);
    //lowest drawable
    background.getDrawable(1).setAlpha(0);
    background.getDrawable(2).setAlpha(1); //outermost drawable.

    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int index = (Integer) view.getTag();
            Drawable currentDrawableInLayerDrawable;
            currentDrawableInLayerDrawable = background.getDrawable(index);
            // Change the visibility of each of the fragment layers when swiping left and right.

            if (position <= -1 || position >= 1) {
                currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha(0);
            } else if (position == 0) {
                currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha(255);
            } else {
                currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha((int) (255 - Math.abs(position * 255)));
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Login_Drawable.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:id="@+id/Idofbg3"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/welcome" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:id="@+id/Idofbg2"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/welcome2" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:id="@+id/Idofbg1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/welcome3" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Build.Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "urlinq.android.com.edu_chat_lollipop"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

login_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/loginPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:background = "@drawable/login_drawable"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="285dp"
        android:name="urlinq.android.com.edu_chat.SignUpFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/combined_login"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/eduChatLogo"
        android:background="@drawable/chatlogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please provide login_main.xml layout file

Answer (score 0):

try add this to dependencies

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

Comment: Just did it. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Start with using the viewpager without support libraries like   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

This will help you to isolate the issue is with viewpager or the support libraries.